# Endofunction as Monoid

Tags: haskell, monoids

I'm trying this (for learning purposes):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

instance Monoid (a -> a) where
  mempty = id
  mappend f g = f . g
```

expecting `id <> id` to be equal to `id . id`

However, with `(id <> id) 1` I receive this error:

```
Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Monoid (a -> a)
```

What should I change to run it?

*It's just to understand monoids and Haskell typeclasses better, not for any practical usage*.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. A problem that's probably unrelated to yours is that there is already a standard `Monoid b => Monoid (a->b)` instance, which conflicts with yours. Please try it with a `newtype` wrapper, so you have a “clean slate”. (`newtype Fun a b = Fun (a->b)`, that would be.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout Probably better `newtype Endo a = Endo (a -> a)`, like in Data.Monoid.

Comment: @lisyarus in principle yes, but that would not quite reproduce the characteristics of an instance such as the OP's original proposed one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will need [`{-# OVERLAPPING #-}`](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/SafeHaskell/NewOverlappingInstances) pragma since GHC.Base has an instance for [`Monoid (a -> b)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#line-255) when b is a Monoid:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
import Data.Monoid (Monoid, mempty, mappend, (<>))

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} Monoid (a -> a) where
    mempty = id
    mappend f g = f . g
```

then, above instance will be invoked for `a -> a`, even if `a` is a Monoid:

```
\> (id <> id) 1
1
\> (id <> id) [1]
[1]
```

whereas with `Monoid b => a -> b` the instance from GHC.Base will be invoked:

```
\> ((:[]) <> (:[])) 1
[1,1]
```

Note that `Data.Monoid` provides [an exact same instance as yours for `a -> a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Data.Monoid.html#line-91) but there the overlap is bypassed using [`newtype Endo a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Endo).

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of Endo but was interested in that particular implementation because it works in Frege: https://github.com/Frege/frege/blob/c1260d53b388e1712f7fbdcda0b5f2cc8b24d4d9/frege/data/Monoid.fr#L90-L92 and I saw articles implying it should work in Haskell as well.

Comment: No overlapping! No! Also, the existing instance makes me sad. I'd much rather have `instance a ~ b => Monoid (a -> b)`, which precisely matches `instance Category (->)`. The `on` version should clearly have a newtype wrapper.

Comment: @dfeuer I'm afraid your response is obscure for casual reader (like me).

Comment: @IvanKleshnin, I've expanded it into an answer.

Answer (score 4):

The Haskell `Category` class offers methods to work with categories whose objects are precisely the Haskell types of some kind. Specifically,

```
class Category c where
  id :: c x x
  (.) :: c y z -> c x y -> c x z
```

The names of the methods should look very familiar. Notably,

```
instance Category (->) where
  id x = x
  f . g = \x -> f (g x)
```

You probably know that monoids are semigroups with identities, expressed in Haskell using

```
class Monoid a where
  mappend :: a -> a -> a
  mempty :: a
```

But another mathematical perspective is that they're categories with exactly one object. If we have a monoid, we can easily turn it into a category:

```
-- We don't really need this extension, but
-- invoking it will make the code below more useful.
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}

import Control.Category
import Data.Monoid
import Prelude hiding ((.), id)

newtype Mon m a b = Mon m

instance Monoid m => Category (Mon m) where
  id = Mon mempty
  Mon x . Mon y = Mon (x `mappend` y)
```

Going the other way is a little bit trickier. One way to do it is to choose a kind with exactly one type, and look at categories whose sole object is that type (prepare for yucky code, which you can skip if you like; the bit below is less scary). This shows that we can freely convert between a `Category` whose object is the type `'()` in the `()` kind and a `Monoid`. The arrows of the category become the elements of the monoid.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, PolyKinds #-}

data Cat (c :: () -> () -> *) where
  Cat :: c '() '() -> Cat c
instance Category c => Monoid (Cat c) where
  mempty = Cat id
  Cat f `mappend` Cat g = Cat (f . g)
```

But this is yucky! Ew! And pinning things down so tightly doesn't usually accomplish anything from a *practical* perspective. But we can get the *functionality* without so much mess, by playing a little trick!

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, PolyKinds #-} 

import Control.Category
import Data.Monoid
import Prelude hiding ((.), id)

newtype Cat' (c :: k -> k -> *) (a :: k) (b :: k) = Cat' (c a b)

instance (a ~ b, Category c) => Monoid (Cat' c a b) where
  mempty = Cat' id
  Cat' f `mappend` Cat' g = Cat' (f . g)
```

Instead of confining ourselves to a `Category` that really only has one object, we simply confine ourselves to looking at *one object at a time*.

The existing `Monoid` instance for functions makes me sad. I think it would be much more *natural* to use a `Monoid` instance for functions based on their `Category` instance, using the `Cat'` approach:

```
instance a ~ b => Monoid (a -> b) where
  mempty = id
  mappend = (.)
```

Since there's already a `Monoid` instance, and overlapping instances are evil, we have to make do with a `newtype`. We could just use

```
newtype Morph a b = Morph {appMorph :: a -> b}
```

and then write

```
instance a ~ b => Monoid (Morph a b) where
  mempty = Morph id
  Morph f `mappend` Morph g = Morph (f . g)
```

and for some purposes maybe this is the way to go, but since we're using a `newtype` already we usually might as well drop the non-standard equality context and use `Data.Monoid.Endo`, which builds that equality into the type:

```
newtype Endo a = Endo {appEndo :: a -> a}

instance Monoid (Endo a) where
  mempty = Endo id
  Endo f `mappend` Endo g = Endo (f . g)
```